# i want to return List<DictionaryClass<string,string>> from web service but getting error for IDictionary

Tags: asp.net

```
  [WebMethod]
    public List<DictionaryClass<string,string>> GetDataByModuleDictionary(string ModuleName)
    {

        return BAL_GeneralService.GetDataByModuleDictionary(ModuleName);
    }

here i m getting the following error...

    The type DictionaryClass`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary.
```

Answer (score 0):

XMLSerializer cannot serialize a class that implements IDictionary.  To work around this you need to implement System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable in your DictionaryClass.  See [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/rakeshrajan/archive/2006/01/15/81105.aspx) for further info.

Comment: Yeah you could probably convert it to a data table and return a list of datatables.  That would probably be about as much work as implementing IXmlSerializable.  You could also try converting it to something else using LINQ, but i can't think what you might convert it to.